# Throttle derived state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, throttling

Here's my use case, a simple React component with a text input which filters the elements of a list:

```
const myArray = [...];

// Inside React component:

handleChange = ({target: {value}}) => this.setState({value});

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />
      <ul>
        {myArray.filter(v => v.includes(this.state.value)).map(v => <li>{v}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

With this code, everytime I change the text inside the input, the elements inside the list changes immediately.

What I want to achieve: the user types in the filter text, that text updates immediately in the text input (normal), but I wish the elements inside the list **not** to update immediately, but let's say 500ms after the user finished typing.

So basically:

- user types, text updates inside `<input>`, list elements don't
- user stops typing, 500ms after, list elements update

Edit:

What I tried:

```
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
const myArray = [...];

// Inside React component:

handleChange = ({target: {value}}) => this.setState({value});

calculateMatches = throttle(() => {
  const matches = myArray.filter(v => v.includes(this.state.value))
  return matches;
}, 500);

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />
      <ul>
        {this.calculateMatches().map(v => <li>{v}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this throttles every 500ms, so if the user continues typing for 1600ms, it will re-update the list 3 times.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of what you've tried when attempting to solve this issue.

Comment: Would you mind using lodash?

Comment: You can use `debounce` from lodash for that very purpose

Comment: @zzzzBov Added. Oblosys and SrTHompson See the comment below my edit, why I wouldn't use throttle/debounce directly.

Comment: @SrThompson My bad, debounce works perfectly.

Comment: Check this article for a nice description of the two: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/